# Core Data Fetch Result Not Convert NsManaged sub class

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4

```
    class DeviceModel: NSManagedObject {

            @NSManaged var deviceName: String?;
            @NSManaged var devicePrice: String?;

    }

class DeviceListController: UIViewController {

    var deviceList: [Any] = [];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();


    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);

        let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Device");

        do {
            self.deviceList =  try context.fetch(request);
        } catch  {
            print(error);
        }
    }
}


extension DeviceListController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.deviceList.count;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DeviceItemCell.reuiseIdentifier) as? DeviceItemCell  else {
            fatalError("Error create tableCell")
        }

        guard let item = deviceList[indexPath.row] as? DeviceModel else {
            fatalError("Item not convertable DeviceModel");
        }

        cell.deviceName.text = item.value(forKey: "devicePrice") as! String

        return cell;

    }
}
```

> let item = deviceList[indexPath.row] as? NSManagedObject is work but
>   when I change NSManagedObject to my DeviceModel class guard return
>   error why i dont convert item to DeviceModel class? But DeviceModel
>   class is sub class NsManagedObject

Comment: Can you please update your code how you are fetching the devicelist?

Comment: I Update my code Add Fetch CoreData

Comment: **Never** declare a datasource array as `[Any]` if you know the static type. It's the worst choice. Are `Device` and `DeviceModel` two different classes? If yes declare `deviceList` as `[NSManagedObject]`, if no declare it as array of the `NSManagedObject` subclass.

Comment: i declared [Any] because try context.fetch(request); return array type ANY